# iPhone camera images as OpenGL ES textures

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, camera, texture-mapping

Is it possible to use an image captured with the iPhone's camera as a texture that is then manipulated in OpenGL ES (flag wave effect, etc.)?  The main problem being the size of the iPhone screen being 320x480 (no status bar) and thus the image won't have dimensions that are power-of-2.  Is the main option copying it into a 512x512 texture and adjusting the vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to do it.

Just use a larger texture. It's a waste of memory but unfortunately there is no way around this problem.

Comment: Does the iPhone OpenGL ES standard allow for the     GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two extension?  This may be worth looking into.

Comment: However, the SGX (as in the 3GS and the iPhone 4, third generation iPod Touches of at least 16gb and above and the iPad) does support GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot (http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot.txt).

Comment: Does anybody have any sample code that shows iPhone camera capture rendering on a 3d surface in real time?  If this is possible, what is the fps rate on the iphone 4?  Also, is the code used to do this approved by the App Store?

Comment: I can't show code for commercial reasons, but it's a completely valid use of the AVFoundation introduction in iOS 4.0 and I've got 30fps video working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be deviding the picture into squares with a length and height of 32 pixels (aka tiling), resulting into 15x8 tiles.  Displaying it would however involve many texture switches while drawing which might become a bottleneck. On the other hand you would save a lot of memory using a tiled approach.